# How to return specific order of results from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following table which contains postIds and maps to a rootPostId

```
CREATE TABLE "PostMap" (
    "postId" BIGINT,
    "rootPostId" BIGINT );


INSERT INTO "PostMap" ("postId","rootPostId") VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO "PostMap" ("postId","rootPostId") VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO "PostMap" ("postId","rootPostId") VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO "PostMap" ("postId","rootPostId") VALUES (4,1);

postId,rootPostId
1,1
2,1
3,3
4,1
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT "postId"
FROM "PostMap" 
WHERE "rootPostId" = (
    SELECT "rootPostId"
    FROM "PostMap"
    WHERE "postId" = 2
    )
```

Which returns the results:

```
postId
1,
2,
4
```

I would like the following returned so that the **first** postId returned is the corresponding postId passed into the query (postId = 2) like the following.

Desired results returned:

```
postId
2,
1,
4
```

Comment: The typical solution is to add a "score" column to the query that tells which result is more relevant. Then you just sort by the score column.

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
order by (postid = 2) desc
```

This should work in both Postgres and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would use case to configure the column you want to order by in any way.

I guess the "2" in the example should be a parameter.  Anyhow, try this query:

```
     SELECT "postId"
        FROM "PostMap" 
        WHERE "rootPostId" = (
            SELECT "rootPostId"
            FROM "PostMap"
            WHERE "postId" = 2
            )
        order by case when "postId" = 2 then 0
                    else 1 + "postId"
                    end
    ;
```

As you can see, we order the query by the case which will be zero when postId = 2 and 1 + PostId in any other case, and so, greater than zero and still ordered by postid.

Using a parameter (:SelectedPost) instead of value 2:

```
SELECT "postId"
FROM "PostMap" 
WHERE "rootPostId" = (
    SELECT "rootPostId"
    FROM "PostMap"
    WHERE "postId" = :SelectedPost
    )
order by case when "postId" = :SelectedPost then 0
            else 1 + "postId"
            end
;
```

Comment: Well, while I was answering I guess previous answer showed to be good enough.  Good.